# Update statement in trigger takes longer to execute than executing it outside of trigger

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a trigger for `After Update`

This trigger works on a server which is going to update 2 tables on a linked server

See code

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tgAfterUpdate] ON  [dbo].[KS_3EToVision]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION    -- Start the transaction

  DECLARE @MatterNumber varchar(15);
  SELECT @MatterNumber = i.MatterNumber FROM inserted i; 

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [FSSQLDEV01].[collnab].[dbo].[collection_header] WHERE         Ch_file_number COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = @MatterNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
       --UPDATE
        IF (SELECT Ch_matter_status FROM [FSSQLDEV01].[collnab].[dbo].[collection_header] WHERE Ch_file_number COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = @MatterNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT ) = 'Current'
             BEGIN 
                --Parent table 
                UPDATE [FSSQLDEV01].[collnab].[dbo].[collection_header]
                SET 
                    Ch_start_date = i.OpenDate 
                FROM 
                    Inserted i 
                WHERE ch_file_number COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = @MatterNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT  

                ----Child table 
                UPDATE [FSSQLDEV01].[collnab].[dbo].[collections] 
                SET 
                    Defendant_1 = i.Description 
                    , Loan_Number_1 = i.Comments 
                    , Client = i.KS_BookName 
                    , Date_Instructed = i.OpenDate 
                    , Person_Responsible_name = i.ResponsibleFeeEarnerName 
                    , Person_Responsible_Email = i.ResponsibleFeeEarnerEmail 
                    , Person_Acting_name = i.BillingFeeEarnerName 
                    , Person_Acting_email = i.BillingFeeEarnerEmail 
                    , Agent_Acting_name = i.BillingFeeEarnerName 
                    , Agent_Acting_email = i.BillingFeeEarnerEmail 
                    , CBA_Panel_Service_Area = i.KS_ServiceCat 
                    , HBN_Number = i.KS_ClientAcctRef 
                    , St_George_Contact = i.KS_Instructor 
                FROM 
                    Inserted i 
                WHERE Left(Collections.file_number,6) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = @MatterNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
             END

--If we reach here, success!
   COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- Whoops, there was an error
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     ROLLBACK

  -- Raise an error with the details of the exception
  DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
  SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
     @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

  RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
END CATCH

END
```

if i try the update statement with the same criteria outside of the trigger it will only take 1 second but inside the trigger it can take upto 45 seconds.

I have narrowed it down to the second update statement being the problem, because if i remove  the second update statement it will execute quickly.

I have also attached an image the shows

I also have a Trigger for Insert and this works quickly within a second And one for Deleting which will take an extended period with in the trigger but functions fine if i remove the 2 delete statements outside of the trigger.

```
USE [TE_3E_TRG]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tgAfterDelete]    Script Date: 08/30/2012 11:24:33 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tgAfterDelete] ON  [dbo].[KS_3EToVision]
   AFTER DELETE
AS 

begin

BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION    -- Start the transaction
            Begin
                --Parent table 
                DELETE FROM [FSSQLDEV01].[collnab].[dbo].[collection_header] WHERE ch_file_number COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = (SELECT d.MatterNumber FROM deleted  d) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

                --Child table 
                DELETE FROM [FSSQLDEV01].[collnab].[dbo].[collections] WHERE Left(file_number,6) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = (SELECT d.MatterNumber FROM deleted  d) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT            

            END
   -- If we reach here, success!
   COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- Whoops, there was an error
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     ROLLBACK

  -- Raise an error with the details of the exception
  DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
  SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
         @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

  RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
END CATCH
```

Does anyone know why this drastic difference in execution time may occur between executing the statements within the trigger and out side of the trigger?

Comment: Side-note: this line ` SELECT @MatterNumber = i.MatterNumber FROM inserted i; ` right at the beginning of your trigger will fail **horribly** when your `UPDATE` statement should ever affect more than one row. The trigger is fired **once per statement** and both the `Inserted` as well as `Deleted` pseudo tables might contain **multiple rows** in such a case. You can never rely on the fact that the `Inserted` table only contains a single row!

Comment: Possibly the issue is that the remote tables are modified within a single transaction (which thus becomes a distributed transaction), and that probably adds some overhead. I'm far from being sure, though, and hope I'll be corrected if I'm utterly wrong.

Comment: Of course, the fact that you are applying a function (`LEFT()`) to a column in the WHERE clause doesn't help matters either.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining remote table with local virtual Inserted table. This probably involves copying whole table from remote server to local and filtering locally.

This is the very rare case where using cursor and updating line by line would probably impove performance.

BTW marc_s's point is correct, your code should account for a possibility where inserted table  has more than 1 row.